# (Glide) Getting image from cache if it exists

Tags: android, imageview, android-glide

I have trouble when I'm using Glide in my app. As I've understood, if image was downloaded once and I request image from cache from other activity, Glide must show image quick. And I got this behavior, but not in my app. Image loads very slow (about 3 seconds), although in another app it was about 0.4 second.
My code with calling Glide:

```
    Glide.with(this)
            .load(url)
            .signature(new StringSignature(url))
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(mHeader);
```

And in other activity code are same.
May you help me? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `signature(url)` part, the model (`url` String in your case) is already a part of the cache key.

The problem may be that your header changes size. The view size (= resulting Bitmap size) needs to be constant for a cache hit. However since you're doing `ALL` caching the load should still be fast. Is there anything changing in the url maybe, like a sessionid or similar? That would make the cache miss.

If the url you're loading is an animated GIF `RESULT` caching can be the culprit, [here's a reference](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/358).